# Debian /etc/hosts has unusual entry

Tags: hosts

I switched from Ubuntu to Debian

And in debian the `/etc/hosts` file after a new install is (on a cloud server):

```
127.0.1.1   static.246.62.63.178.clients.your-server.de static

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What is `static.246.62.63.178.clients.your-server.de` ?

Seems like [the ip address is reserved for future use](https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/246.62.63.178).

Do I leave it in place of replace it? E.g. is this okay (if my server is example.com):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost example.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback example.com
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: The installer might have got that hostname from DHCP, and I don't think it's unusual for installers to write a configured hostname to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @roaima, that is quite quirky and interesting. I still don't know where the IP address 178.63.62.246 comes from though.

Comment: For me this is the hostname of your VM, provided by your hosting provider. And probably 178.63.62.246 si the public address of your host.

Comment: Odd... on my Debian derivative (RPi OS), using the hostname for 127.0.1.1 is advised for use with Zero-conf networking (on a LAN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IP address-as-a-name would usually be read in reverse (much like a DNS `PTR` entry), so the name should correspond to 178.63.62.246 rather than 246.62.63.178.

In this instance that would suggest a server from Hetzner.

You can remove the entry, but if that's what the machine is called - what it's known as - it would be prudent to have an entry of some sort. For example

```
127.0.0.1      localhost loopback
178.63.62.246  my.preferred.hostname.example.com
178.63.62.246  static.246.62.63.178.clients.your-server.de
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @roaima's answer is correct, but [Debian has some more information](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_hostname_resolution) on this if you're interested. Specifically wrt the use of 127.0.1.1:

> For a system with a permanent IP address, that permanent IP address should be used here instead of 127.0.1.1.

It's interesting that Debian *(apparently)* wrote this entry in your `/etc/hosts` file, and more so that the string has the word `static` in it.

Comment: `static` is a hostname, and as far I know, it is Hetzner that modify such file (and other) on their images.

Comment: So, `on a cloud server` means that the hosting service Hetzner has root privileges? I didn't understand it that way, but you're probably correct. Still seems an odd setup to me, but I've not had a hosted server for ages.

Comment: I had several root server (metal, not virtual) on Hetzner. You can get also just virtual servers (with root). I think they do also "usual hosting" (but there is much more rivals on that market). Being able to select distros from a list, or being able to install and configure apache or other webservers and other packages, or deploy any container, and having own IP, etc. it is often an advantage (but it costs more then usual webhosting).